# Parsing json_decode output

Tags: php, json

Im a little stuck on parsing json output. I am working blind with json and have tried some tutorials but cant seem to find what im looking for.

I am trying to use a service providers API which is doing the functions correctly. I am then getting the correct feedback from the provider in json format.

My code so far looks like;

```
$response = curl_exec($apicall);
$json_output = json_decode($response);
var_dump($json_output);
```

This then returns;

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
["status"]=>
string(2) "OK"
["droplet"]=>
object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
["id"]=>
int(490021)
["name"]=>
string(20) "test.mydomain.com"
["image_id"]=>
int(374535)
["size_id"]=>
int(66)
["event_id"]=>
int(6403716)
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to store the "OK" from "status" and the "490021" from "id" as variables.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to store them as variables. When you use `json_decode`, it'll create a `stdClass` which you can access the variables, like:

```
$json_output = json_decode($response);
echo $json_output->id;
```

Comment: oh. so it would be $json_output->status; then $json_output->droplet->id; ?

Comment: @imukcedup exactly that. If you'd prefer working with arrays, you can pass `true` into the second parameter of `json_decode` and you can use `$json_output` as an `array` instead of an `object`.